# Update all imports with Absolute Imports react

Tags: reactjs

I've implemented Absolute imports with a `jsonconfig.json` file in the root of my folder with the following code

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

It's working perfectly with no issues as if yet but I've encountered a bit of another issue that I want to fix. I would like to know how I update my older imports that look like this `.../.../.../`,`./` or `../` etc with the way I've set up it in the `jsonconfig.json`

I know this is going to sound lazy but I don't really want to do it manually because the project that I'm currently working on is MASSIVE and going through each and every file and updating it is going to be a pain and very very tedious.